# Looking for C/C++ pre-processor macro or template to reverse a hex macro array and generate hex number

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I have a very specific question. I have the following macro define to be used in code later.

```
#define MY_ARRAY { 0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77 \
                   0x88, 0x99, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD, 0xEE, 0xFF}
```

Now I want to reverse the ordering during compile time and generate a value to be directly embedded in the executable during compile time. So basically, I want the following code

```
long x = DO_IT(MY_ARRAY);
long y = DO_TOO(MY_ARRAY);
```

so that at compile time

```
x = 0x7766554433221100;
y = 0xFFEEDDCCBBAA9988;
```

How would my **DO_IT** and **DO_TOO** have to look like for this to work? I am really struggling with this one and can't seem to find a working solution. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your array always have the same number elements? Can you modify your `MY_ARRAY` macro so that it doesn't include the braces? And why do you want to do it with a macro and not with a function?

Comment: It actually contains 16 elements (I will update the question). 64 bit hex number. It does contain the braces as it is needed later in the legacy code I am working on.

Comment: `#define reverse(a, b) b, a` ? `DO_IT` is impossible - it's impossible to remove `{` `}` at preprocessor. Can you remove the `{` `}` ? Also what happened to `0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD, 0xEE, 0xFF`?

Comment: But that won't fit into a 64-bit int; you'd need 128 bits. If you can define `MY_ARRAY` in two stages -- one without braces, the other with braces -- you can then create the number with bt-shifting: `#define(A0, A1, ...) (((A0) << 0) | ((A1) << 8) | ...)`

Comment: C and C++ are different languages, and C++ can do more complex compile-time calculations - not based on macros - than C. Choose your language.

Comment: Ok, it is more complicated than I thought. It is actually 16 bytes array that needs to be stored in 2 variables. God, help me. 

We are using a C++ compiler so I can use C++ features (though they are not used yet as it is legacy C code).

Comment: `0x77 \
                   0x88` comma is missing, by intention or a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove `{` `}` you can just:

```
#define MY_ARRAY  0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77
#define DO_IT_2(_0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7)  (\
     (unsigned long long)(_7) << (7 * 8) | \
     (unsigned long long)(_6) << (6 * 8) | \
     etc...            \
     (unsigned long long)(_0) << (0 * 8))
#define DO_IT(x)  DO_IT_2(x)
```

update:

```
#define MY_ARRAY2 0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77,
               0x88, 0x99, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD, 0xEE, 0xFF
#define REVERSE_LL_8(_0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7)  (\
     (unsigned long long)(_7) << (7 * 8) | \
     (unsigned long long)(_6) << (6 * 8) | \
     etc...            \
     (unsigned long long)(_0) << (0 * 8))
#define DO_IT_2(_0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,...)  \
        REVERSE_LL_8(_0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7)
#define DO_IT(x) DO_IT_2(x)
#define DO_TOO_2(a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,_0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7)  \
        REVERSE_LL_8(_0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7)
#define DO_TOO(x) DO_TOO_2(x)

DO_IT(MY_ARRAY2)
DO_TOO(MY_ARRAY2)
```

> so I can use C++ features

In C++ it's a really simple `contexpr` function with `initializer_list`:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#define MY_ARRAY  {0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77}
constexpr unsigned long long DO_IT(const std::initializer_list<int>& l) {
    unsigned long long r = 0;
    for (auto&& i : l) {
        r >>= 8;
        r |= (unsigned long long)i << (7 * 8);
    }
    return r;
}
constexpr long a = DO_IT(MY_ARRAY);
```

Comment: Ok, yeah. Actually, I can just remove the braces and add them via another macro for the legacy code and basically use MY_ARRAY_RAW like this and then have a MY_ARRAY be a { MY_ARRAY_RAW }. I will try that. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you!!! It worked using macros. I had to do some changes though as I am using MSVC and is not adhering to the standard when expanding arguments. I found a solution though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35210637/macro-expansion-argument-with-commas

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't seem like there's any reason to use macros here, you just need compile-time evaluation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define MY_INIT_LIST { 0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, \
                       0x88, 0x99, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD, 0xEE, 0xFF, }
#define MY_ARRAY (const uint32_t[]) MY_INIT_LIST

int main (void) 
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<16; i++)
    printf("%X ", MY_ARRAY[i]);

  const uint32_t u32 = MY_ARRAY[3] << 24 |
                       MY_ARRAY[2] << 16 |
                       MY_ARRAY[1] <<  8 |
                       MY_ARRAY[0] <<  0 ;
  printf("\n%X\n", u32);
}
```

This is endianess independent and standard C. It can trivially be rewritten to use 64 bit types which is probably(?) what you actually want?

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look at Boost library's solution: 
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/array_reverse.html

**BOOST_PP_ARRAY_REVERSE** is what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I rather not add the boost library if I can help it.